# Excel: I have two working formulas. Need to get them to run based on =IF(WEEKDAY)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, weekday

Im building a schedule rotation in which a group of employees are either Primary oncall, Secondary oncall, or not OnCall at all.

I have a row in my spreadsheet that validates if both primary and secondary are covered on any given day, however secondaries are not used on weekends. (P=primary, WP=Weekend Primary, HP=Holiday Primary, same with secondaries for tracking purposes)

In the examples below row 3 houses the dates, beginning in column B as the first of the month, B3=5/1/2020 (which is a Friday), C3=5/2/2020 (Saturday), etc

This works for Monday through Friday:
`=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"p")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hp")))=1)*(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"s")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"ws"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hs")))=1),"G","B")`

This works for Weekends:
`=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"p")+(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"Hp")))=1),"G","B")`

The problem is every month when I go to do the next schedule, i have to rearrange the the formulas in this row so they pine up below weekdays or weekends, respectively. Id like to combine these formulas into an =IF(Weekend,,2)<6,`weekday formula`, else `weekend formula`

My Attempt
`=IF((WEEKDAY,B$3,2)<6,IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"p")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hp")))=1)*(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"s")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"ws"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hs")))=1),"G","B"),IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"p")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hp")))=1),"G","B"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong brackets in the IF condition.

yours
=IF((WEEKDAY,B$3,2)<6,

correct
=IF(WEEKDAY(B$3,2)<6,

**Background:** The default for the Weekday() function returns 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc and 7 for Saturday.

If you want to run a formula if the week day is Monday through Friday, then you need to test if the returned number is greater than 1 and also smaller than 7. You can wrap an AND() function around two Weekday() functions for the IF condition like this:

```
=if(AND(Weekday(A1)>1,Weekday(A1)<7)),WeekdayFormula,WeekendFormula)
```

To avoid the complicated AND construct for the IF condition, you may want to use the parameter `2` in the Weekday() function. This will return Monday as 1 and Sunday as 7 and all you need to check for a weekday is if the number is smaller than 6. Like this:

```
=if(Weekday(A1,2)<6,WeekdayFormua,WeekendFormula)
```

Comment: I *AM* using the `2` parameter in the WEEKDAY() function. The AND, is apart of the other formula `=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"p")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hp")))=1)*(SUM(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"s")+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"ws"))+(COUNTIF(B5:B11,"Hs")))=1),"G","B")` which is looking for p, wp, hp, s, ws, or hs in the cells on weekdays, and the other formula `=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"p")+(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"wp"))+(COUNTIF(C5:C11,"Hp")))=1),"G","B")` which is looking for only p, wp, or hp on weekENDS.

Comment: I know that you are using the 2 as the second parameter. I posted the info about that parameter as "Background", as you can see. The issue with your formula is the wrong placement of the brackets. Did you read that? What happens if you correct your formula by placing the brackets correctly? If it's still not working, post your corrected formula.

Comment: That worked perfeclty. Sorry I misunderstood the AND statement that you were referring to.

Thanks!